# Tkinter Python parando o script

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de criar uma janela com os dizeres "Aplicação rodando" e tentei o seguinte:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Aplicação rodando")
mainloop()
*** Resto do meu script aqui... ***
```

No entanto eu notei que o meu script só começa a ser executado quando fecho a janela criada pelo tkinter, é possivel manter a janela aberta enquanto meu script esta sendo executado ?

Comment: Sim, tem, mas você sabe o que a função `mainloop` faz?

Comment: Opa Anderson, na vdd eu não faço ideia. O meu script atual grava um áudio via microfone, transforma num arquivo de áudio, esse arquivo de áudio é processado e o que o usuário disse retorna num .txt, no entanto notei que o usuário não sabia que estava sendo gravado e queria algo bem sintético por isso eu só tentei copiar um script da internet.

Comment: Pegue a dica do @AndersonCarlosWoss e estude o que `mainloop()` faz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a linha `mainloop()` está segurando a execução. Essa função  entrega ao tkinter o controle do script, para que ele fique respondendo eventos, como pressionamento de botões, etc, até que ele seja fechado.

Para evitar que o Tkinter faça isso, remova essa linha. Coloque `root.update()` no lugar para atualizar a tela, e o seu script continuará rodando (porém sem responder a eventos de janela)

Comment: Muito obrigado nosklo.